# Display image from database in PHP

Tags: alert

i was trying to read an image from database in PHP,but it was showing image on whole page. i want to display image on a html page. please help

```
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM images";
    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die("Invalid query: " . mysql_error());

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
          { 
             header("Content-type: image/jpeg");            
              echo $row[1];                     
          }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, if image is stored in db as blob type... here is idea (i guess there are more elegant solutions, but this one is working too).

In your main file, inside html output, make this loop (session_start() at the begining of page, of course):

```
$i=-1;

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
          { 
          $i++;



         $_SESSION['img'][]=$row['data']; //'data' is field name in my db, you //should change it to appropriate field name... 



         echo "<img src='img.php?id=".$i."'>";





          }
```

Your img.php should look like this:

```
session_start();
header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
$id=$_GET['id'];
echo $_SESSION['img'][$id];
exit;
```

So, this will work with array of images, and with single image, too... So -> code stores image data in session array, img.php showing images from array, inside loop on main page...

Answer (score 0):

You can display it like this :

```
      while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
      { 
         echo "<img src=$row[1] />";                 
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you store the image path in your database.

Use this  to display the image 200*200 size.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  { 
     echo "<img with='200' height='200' src=$row[1] />";                 
  }
```