# how do I display a BLOB image through php database

Tags: php, html, sql

i have tried to display an image from the php database and every time i load this code it takes me to a new page and it give me "image not able to be displayed" thing

```
<?php
while($data= mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
?>
<img src=<?php   
$image=$data['image'];
header("content-type: image/jpeg");
echo $image;
?>
/>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Why are you storing the BLOB in the DB, rather than the path to the image? It seems like a terrible way of doing it, as the filesystem is faster to access.

Comment: Do you understand the difference between the path to an image and imagefile itself?

Comment: because i want things to be manipulated by people that don't have access to my account

Comment: if there is a way that people can upload it directly to my file directory that would work too

Comment: Try with this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17009191/display-image-from-database-in-php/

Comment: yes that would be ideal and i have done that before but now i want to make it so people who do not have access to my file directory can upload images as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

send it to a to a different page on php and call it like this

```
<img src="differentpage.php?id=<?php echo id ?>">
```

Comment: Where is the `id` constant defined?

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a php file, for example image.php. Inside it you can put something like that:

```
<?php
   //Your code to call database for image id (from _GET['id']), for instance:
   $image_id = $_GET['id'];
   $data = mysql_query("Select image from images where id = $image_id");

   while($data = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){ 
      $image=$data['image'];
      header("content-type: image/jpeg");
      echo $image;
   }
?>
```

Then, in your view, you can do:

```
<img src="image.php?id=IMAGE_ID" />
```

Greetings!

Comment: I'd swap the `while` for an `if`. Ah, and you have a SQL injection hole in this as well - would you fix?